# How to find max Amount per month (for the year)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm just starting with Pandas, and Python. I have a CSV dump for the yearly transactions from my bank. Every tax season, I'm required to prepare a report of max values reached during each month (and the specific date), and the max value overall:

**Sample data:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Date': ['2018-01-01','2018-01-05', '2018-05-01'],
                        'Transaction': ['CREDIT', 'DEBIT', 'CREDIT'],
                         'Amount': [100.20, -50.00, 200.00]})
```

I can't figure out how to use pd.to_datetime on an inline DataFrame.

Tried `df['Date'].apply(pd.to_datetime)` but got an error

> ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', 'CREDIT', 'occurred at index 
>       # Transaction')

```
df = pd.read_csv("~/Downloads/cheq.csv", parse_dates=[0], na_values="n/a")
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Date', 'Transaction', 'Amount'])
df.set_index(['Date'], drop=True, inplace=True)

grouped = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="M"))  # DataFrameGroupBy (grouped by Month)

for g, v in grouped:
   print(g, v.max())
```

Output:

```
2018-01-31 00:00:00 Transaction     DEBIT
Amount         100.02
dtype: object
2018-02-28 00:00:00 Transaction    CREDIT
Amount            200
dtype: object
```

**What I would like to see is (some form of):**

```
2018-01-01 00:00:00 Transaction     DEBIT
Amount         100.02
2018-02-01 00:00:00 Transaction    CREDIT
Amount            200
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the convert the date format and then apply groupBy.
Try this!

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Date': ['2018-01-01','2018-01-05', '2018-05-01'],
             'Transaction': ['CREDIT', 'DEBIT', 'CREDIT'],
             'Amount': [100.20, -50.00, 200.00]})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
print(df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%B')).max())

#output:
         Amount       Date Transaction
Date                                  
January   100.2 2018-01-05       DEBIT
May       200.0 2018-05-01      CREDIT
```

Comment: Almost, there! How would I add the date, not just the month? E.g. January-2, May-1, etc?

Comment: just add %d in strftime. please find my updated solution

Comment: That gives me both entries, but I only wanted the max per month, so this seems to work:
`print(df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%B'))['Date', 'Amount', 'Transaction'].max())`


`               Date  Amount Transaction`
`Date`                                   

`February 2018-02-01   200.0      CREDIT`

`January  2018-01-05   100.2       DEBIT`

Comment: you want max date for every month is it?

Comment: then you can remove `['Date', 'Amount', 'Transaction']` because by default it takes all the columns

Comment: Thanks a lot @AI_Learning. I've been at this for over 4 hours. I get it now... Why Python is used in Data Sciences. You, sir. Rock. And have the greatest New Year!